# How to select all f:selectItems inside p:selectOneRadio with javascript in JSF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

My jsf code is the following:

```
  <p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{obj.idcStatus}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Approve" itemValue="#{true}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Disapprove" itemValue="#{false}" />
  </p:selectOneRadio>
```

And I want to add a selectOneRadio that can select all items from the selectOneRadio (`id="options"`), like this:

[image]

How to make this work??

Thanks.

Comment: You can add listener for top group (mean "all") of radio. So, change on them could set value **using $("selector").val()** for another groups, that could be selected with class, for example. Can you provide your code please?

Comment: Can you provide code for any of subitem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give those radio buttons an unique style class, e.g. `styleClass="status"`.

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="all">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Approve all" itemValue="#{true}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Disapprove all" itemValue="#{false}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <p:column>#{item.value}</p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:selectOneRadio id="status" value="#{item.status}" styleClass="status">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Approve" itemValue="#{true}" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Disapprove" itemValue="#{false}" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Once done that, then there are 2 general approaches to achieve the functional requirement:

1. Client side, using jQuery:

   ```
   <p:selectOneRadio id="all" onchange="$('.status .ui-radiobutton:has([value=' + this.value + ']) .ui-radiobutton-box').click()">
       ...
   </p:selectOneRadio>
   ```
2. Server side, using JSF ajax:

   ```
   <p:selectOneRadio id="all">
       ...
       <p:ajax listener="#{bean.updateStatus(component.value)}" update="@(.status)" />
   </p:selectOneRadio>
   ```

   With this new bean method:

   ```
   public void updateStatus(boolean newStatus) {
       for (Item item : items) {
           item.setStatus(newStatus);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Almost done... I used jQuery as you suggested, and the first item isn't being selected, is there any reason? Maybe because the index of the first element is zero?

Comment: Works for me at PF5. Which PF version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this "PF" terminology, what you mean? I'm brazilian. =)

Comment: It's short for PrimeFaces.

Comment: oh, of course, prime faces! :S.. I'm using version 3.4.1... Anyway, how can I expand this code: $('.status .ui-radiobutton:has([value=' + this.value + ']) .ui-radiobutton-box').click() and put inside <h:outputScript target="body"> tag?